# Updating all rows at once in mysql table with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table seller whose columns are

```
id   mobile1
1    787811
```

I have another table with same columns ,I just want to update the mobile1 field from this table with the values from other table say "copy".
I have written this query

```
UPDATE seller
SET mobile1 = (
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(mobile1, '.', 1)
  FROM copy)
WHERE 1;
```

I am getting this obvious error when I run it.

> Sub-query returns more than 1 row ,
>   Any way to do this??

Comment: you need to get only one value in sub-query, so you need to add where condition in subquery

Comment: Maybe `LIMIT 1` or `WHERE 1` 

Comment: Do you want to get all the `mobile` from the table `copy` and insert them in the `seller` table?

Comment: every value of mobile1 from table copy to respective rows of seller !!

Comment: `LIMIT 1` and `WHERE 1` doesn't mean the same things @VladimirKovpak

Comment: its just i want to copy all data of mobile1 column of copy table to mobile1 table of seller table

Comment: @lOGAN check my answer below then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone who is looking for the possible answer here is what I did,I created a procedure with while loop.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE update_mobile(IN counting BIGINT);

BEGIN
declare x INT default 0;
SET x = 1;
WHILE x <= counting DO
UPDATE copy SET mobile1=(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(mobile1, '.', 1) as mobi FROM seller WHERE id=x LIMIT 1) WHERE id=x;
SET x=x + 1;
  END WHILE;
END
```

AND finally I calculated the number of rows by count(id) and passed this number to my procedure

```
SET @var =count;
CALL update_mobile(@var);
```

AND it worked like a Charm...

Answer (score 1):

You need condition which will be using to select only one row or you should use `LIMIT`:

```
UPDATE seller
SET mobile1 = (
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(mobile1, '.', 1)
  FROM copy
  LIMIT 1)
WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: that will update one single row ,how to update 10000 rows ?? ,anyways i achieved it by stored procedure :)

Answer (score 0):

You can constrain the number of rows returned to just one using [MySQL limit.](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)

```
UPDATE seller SET mobile1=(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(mobile1,'.',1)
FROM copy LIMIT 1)
WHERE id=1;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to copy all data, you can do this :

```
INSERT INTO `seller` (`mobile1`) SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(mobile1,'.',1) FROM copy
```

Comment: I think that the OP posted the incorrect question! In the question he says "Updating table" but in the description, he says "with the values from other table say "copy""